# Alternative to IdentityHashMap where value pairings are not required?

Tags: java

I'm maintaining a piece of software that is using an `IdentityHashMap` to store a list of objects as the `key`, but I noticed that everywhere in the code just populates the paired `value` with null and nothing ever seems to reference the `value` either. This feels wrong to me, I don't know why a map is being used when the value being stored is effectively ignored.

Based on my observations, the map key is being used to store/compare objects and the previous author is using `contains` before populating the map to make sure no attempts to add duplicate objects are made.

I'm not familiar with all the different data structures in Java, but I'm guessing a `collection` is better suited for this purpose. I came to `HashSet` because the order doesn't matter and we don't want duplicates.

Where you guys come in is I'm wondering if my thought process is correct. Is there perhaps something I may not be considering as to why the original author went with `IdentityHashMap`? Would `HashSet` be the appropriate alternative where the value pairings are not required? Are there any performance considerations? (eg. is `IdentityHashMap` actually faster than a `HashSet` in this context?)

If `HashSet` isn't the correct data structure, what is?

Comment: The contract for what constitutes an 'existing' object are not the same for IdentityHashMap and HashSet. You cannot replace one for the other without fully understand why an identity hash map was used in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

[`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) uses `==` to determine if two objects are the same while [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) uses `equals`.

If you want a `Set` with identical semantics to an `IdentityHashMap`, you may wish to check out [`Collections.newSetFromMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29).

```
Set<T> identityHashSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<T, Boolean>());
```

Comment: `newSetFromMap` looks promising, but unfortunately our target is 1.5 :(

Comment: @Nathan You might want to consider trying to target a newer version of Java. 1.5 has been EOL for over 3 years now.

Comment: Additionally, it looks like `newSetFromMap` still has a map underlying it all anyway, it just populates the key value with `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `null`, that's really just an abstraction from what is already being done.

Comment: Re: EOL 1.5, I would love to, but I'm not project lead.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `HashSet` here would provide different behavior. It sounds like the `IdentityHashMap` is being used to check if an object with the same identity exists in the map. If you used a `HashSet`, the `contains` method uses `equals` to compare (where as `IdentityHashMap` uses `==`).

Without knowing more about the problem, I can't speculate as to why this is being done, but to answer your question, a `HashSet` would not be an equivalent substitution.

If you want to use a set because using a map with null values seems incorrect (it does seem a little unclean), consider wrapping the objects in an [identity equivalence](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html#identity%28%29). Then their `equals` methods will delegate to `==`.

Comment: The only references made to this map are `.clear()`, `.containsKey( Object )` and `.put( Object, null )`. It's the fact that the value is never used or referenced that bothers me, hence I am not sure why a map was used in the first place.

Edit: Just saw your edit, I'm not using guava, is there something equivalent in the JDK?

Comment: The map was likely used in the first place so a hash could be done to check if the object exists. Using the IdentityHashMap was the way to be able to hash on equivalence rather than .equals. I don't think there is an equivalent reference object in the jdk, but you could easily write a wrapper that uses == for .equals (or if you haven't implemented equals, I believe the default implementation will use ==).

Comment: Makes sense, I guess, but what doesn't make sense to me is that in this case it wouldn't matter if the objects were equivalent by `.equals()` anyway. I can't see why we'd want to add a different instance of an equivalent object to the map anyway, but I believe there is currently no place it would occur. I guess that's the part where I wonder if there's something else to it, or if the original programmer just didn't use the right tool for the job.